# Name suffixes/prefixes in Middle-earth

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

I know that there are some things in languages of Middle-earth that name someone the son or daughter of another, for instance Thranduilion meaning son of Thranduil.  What language is that specific one?  Perhaps Sindarin?  And how would it be applied to other names? For example, would son of Oropher be Oropherion?

Comment: About what are you really asking? You could call Thranduil Oropherion and that's it - it's simply a gramatic construction; and what does it mean "sounding so strage"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a list question.

Comment: Post-edit, this a question of Sindarin grammar.

Comment: @Shamshiel Agreed. Post-edit it's a fine question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction is actually Quenyan; *-ion* is the male [patronymic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic) suffix:

> [*Quenya Lexicon*] gives *yo*, *yond-* as poetic words for 'son', adding: 'but very common is *-ion* in patronymics (and hence practically = "descendant")
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* II *The Book of Lost Tales Part 2* Appendix: "Names in the Lost Tales Part 2"</sub></sup>

At least one other example (along with some more usage) is given later:

> The 'names of insight' were more often given in the early days of the Eldar, and in that time they came more readily into public use, because it was then still the custom for the father-name of a son to be a modification of the father's name (as Finwë' I Curufinwë) or a patronymic (as Finwion 'son of Finwë).
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* X *Morgoth's Ring* Part 2: The Second Phase Chapter 3: "Laws and Customs Among the Eldar" *Of Naming*</sub></sup>

I'm unable to find any father-names based on "Oropher", but did find one based on the name "Inglor":

> 'I am Gildor, *[...]* Gildor Inglorion of the House of Finrod. We are Exiles, and most of our kindred have long ago departed and we too are now only tarrying here a while, ere we return over the Great Sea.'
>
> <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book 1 Chapter 3: "Three is Company"</sub></sup>

[Gildor's ancestry isn't a cut-and-dry issue](http://www.tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Inglorion#Ancestry), but the Legendarium has almost always had a character who can be called "Inglor", of the house of Finrod.

Based on the *-r* suffix alone, I would speculate that "Son of Oropher" would indeed be constructed as "Oropherion", but I have no firmer evidence.

Comment: Thanks, it's usually you who answers the best.  You're to Scifi and Fantasy SE as rand al'thor is to PSE :).  +1 and the tick(funny name, eh?)

Answer (score 1):

Another example is in the names of the kings of Arnor:

> After Malvegil, the Kings at Fornost again claimed lordship over the whole of Arnor, and took names with the prefix *ar(a)* in token of this.

(from a footnote in Appendix A).